# Some questions around sockets and accept()

Tags: c, sockets, fault-tolerance

Lets say that we have created a socket with `socket()`, then we used `bind()` and `listen()`. Then we use `accept()` to wait for client requests, after a client is connected if we shutdown the server (for example we ctrl+c the process).

1. Is the client still connected to the port ?
2. Can we somehow reestablish connection to the socket ?
3. Is this a client-side issue as well ? Or does `recvfrom()` wait for someone to bind back to the socket ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume you're using TCP.

> If we shutdown the server:

1. Is the client still connected to the port?

   No.  The operating system on the server side will have noticed that the server terminated, and will have closed the connection, sending a packet to the client which ends the connection.  Even if this does not happen (e.g. the network fails), the connection is no longer usable, and the first time the client sends something, it will realize the connection was lost.  Some programs use TCP Keep-Alive or send heartbeat messages to make sure they notice if the server goes away.
2. Can we somehow reestablish connection to the socket?

   No.  The client needs to establish a new connection.
3. Is this a client-side issue as well? Or does recvfrom() wait for someone to bind back to the socket?

   `recvfrom()` does not wait in such a way.  The server cannot "reconnect" or "rebind" in the way you are implying.  The client will need to respond to the disconnection by explicitly reconnecting.

Comment: He is using `listen()` and `accept()`. No assumption necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the information and the time you spent answering.

Comment: @EJP: OP might be using SCTP for example: https://linux.die.net/man/7/sctp - it uses the same functions as TCP.  Obviously TCP is most likely, but it is indeed an assumption.

Comment: OK, so if he was using SCTP how would your answer change? *Would* it change?

Comment: @EJP: SCTP has keep-alive enabled by default, which TCP does not.  SCTP also has multipath, in which case losing a single connection might not require the application to do anything.

Comment: He has lost the entire server, not just a single connection. You haven't mentioned anything that would change your answer AFAICS.

Comment: @EJP: This is really a huge digression.  Feel free to just edit my answer if you like.

Comment: I'm asking because I want to know, not to just argue with you.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the client still connected to the port?

The client will get a connection reset when reading on Windows, or an EOS when reading under *nix, or a connection reset when writing.

> Can we somehow reestablish connection to the socket?

To the *port*. The client can try to reconnect, but it won't succeed until the server is running and listening. The server can't do anything about it after it restarts.

> Is this a client a client-side issue as well?

Yes, see above.

> Or does `recvfrom()` wait for someone to bind back to the socket?

Certainly not.

NB You should be using `recv()` for stream sockets. You don't need the source-address information `recvfrom()` gives you, if indeed it does, because it's already available via `getpeername()` on the socket.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you spent answering and the information you provided

Comment: @MakisMandrelas Thank you for your thanks. It is rare to get them here, unfortunately, and even rarer for anybody to acknowledge the time that responders take to answer. Your courtesy to both John and me is much appreciated.